# Protobuf error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Tags: python, module, protocol-buffers, protoc

I am trying to get Protobuf to work with Python but Python throws an error when trying to import a compiled .proto file.  The error is ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'.

This is on a brand new and clean EC2 instance with Ubuntu Linux.  Installation of the protocol compiler is by downloading a pre-built binary from the release page and then following the instructions in the readme file, as described [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf#protocol-compiler-installation).  The full list of commands is shown below.  The compilation appears to work but the import fails.  What is going wrong?  Thanks in advance.

I use scp to copy my_file.proto from the local machine to the EC2 instance.  Then SSH to the instance and:

```
$ wget https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v21.5/protoc-21.5-linux-x86_64.zip
$ sudo apt install unzip
$ unzip protoc-21.5-linux-x86_64.zip
$ sudo cp bin/protoc /usr/local/bin/.
$ protoc                                      (to test that protoc works)
$ sudo cp -R include/google/ /usr/local/include/.
$ ls /usr/local/include/google/protobuf       (to confirm that the copy worked)
$ export SRC_DIR=/home/ubuntu
$ export DST_DIR=/home/ubuntu
$ protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --python_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/my_file.proto    (works)
$ python3
import my_file_pb2    (fails)
```

The import fails with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'"

`$ which python3` returns `/usr/bin/python3`

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [`protobuf`](https://pypi.org/project/protobuf/) too. `protoc` generates the stubs but Python's Protobuf implementation has a runtime requirement and that's provided by the `protobuf` module.

It's a good idea to use e.g. `virtualenv` to compartmentalize Python workspaces.

```bash
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate

python3 -m pip install protobuf # Or requirements.txt
python3
import my_file_pb2 # should work
```

When you're done

```
deactivate
```

You may also want to keep `protoc` local with:

```bash
unzip protoc-21.5-linux-x86_64.zip -d ${SRC_DIR}/protoc-21.5-linux-x86_64
PATH=${PATH}:${SRC_DIR}/protoc-21.5-linux-x86_64/bin
protoc
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `pip3 install google-api-python-client`.

Or `pip3 install google`, but as I can see it does not seem to work for many people, if it works for you then great.